# Hamburger menu break shrinking header (or vice versa)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Still having issues with this, any help would be great.

I have a hamburger menu (see here: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/zKXARr ), that I want to work with a shrinking header (see here: http://codepen.io/Nickies/pen/ZYwJZM ). Putting the two codes directly together hasn't worked. The shrinking header and resizing logo ceases to function on scrolling.

I am not sure what is causing this. Any advice would be brilliant.

Posting the code my combined version below:
codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/XjQQWZ

```js
(function() {

  var $navUL = $('nav ul');

  $('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('show');
    $navUL.toggleClass('hidden');

  });

})();

function init() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 300,
      header = document.querySelector("header");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      classie.add(header, "smaller");
    } else {
      if (classie.has(header, "smaller")) {
        classie.remove(header, "smaller");
      }
    }
  });
}
window.onload = init();
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";
 $bar-width:50px;
 $bar-height:4px;
 $bar-spacing:15px;
 body {
  background: #000000;
  font-family: Teko;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.hamburger-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  width: $bar-width;
  height: $bar-height + $bar-spacing*2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text {
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.show .text {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}
.bar,
.bar:after,
.bar:before {
  width: $bar-width;
  height: $bar-height;
}
.bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY($bar-spacing);
  background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
  transition: all 0ms 300ms;
  .show & {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
.bar:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: $bar-spacing;
  background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
  transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.bar:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: $bar-spacing;
  background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
  transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.show .bar:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  ;
}
.show .bar:before {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  ;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em;
  border-color: black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #bc31fe;
}
nav ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Teko;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  a {
    @include transition-duration(0.5s);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
.overlay .contacts {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 37px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .01em;
  z-index: 2;
}
.contacts {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #10131a;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
.bigtext {
  font-size: 50em;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #0683c9;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  float: center;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
header nav a {
  line-height: 150px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #9fdbfc;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}
header.smaller {
  height: 75px;
}
header.smaller h1#logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
header.smaller nav a {
  line-height: 75px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  header h1#logo {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  header nav a {
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  header.smaller {
    height: 75px;
  }
  header.smaller h1#logo {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  header.smaller nav {
    height: 35px;
  }
  header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <h1 id="logo">
                LOGO
            </h1>
    <div class="hamburger-menu">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="text">MENU</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- /header -->

<nav>
  <ul role="navigation" class="overlay hidden">
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">RESUME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="contacts">
  <address>someperson@somewhere.com</address>
</div>

<div class="bigtext">THIS IS PLACEHOLDER</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `classie` script in your codepen.
See a working example here http://codepen.io/object505/pen/Vmwwwo

Comment: That's a great help. How do I make it so the hamburger stays in the header? As currently the final purple line drops just below it.  Also with the overlay, when you click on the Menu it is falling behind the header.

Comment: That is simple css. I have updated the pen to include the menu moving on scroll.

Comment: I deleted my last comment, as I figured out what you meant. Thank you for that. My last issue is the overlay menu. I have tried making it a higher z-index, but the overlay still appears under the header when you click on it.